# Did the people who followed the triennial cycle celebrate "Simchat Torah" in the same manner as those who followed the annual cycle?

Tags: calendar, siyum, parsha-torah-portion, simchat-torah

I noticed [this related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10783/why-do-we-have-different-customs-for-the-second-day-of-shmini-atzeret-in-the-dia) that briefly discusses Simchat Torah, but it mainly answers those that follow the annual cycle.

People following the annual cycle clebrate Simchat Torah on a Yom Tov (in Israel, on Shmini Atzeret, outside on 9th day after start of Succot.) It is celebrated on a Yom-Tov, specifically (i.e. - not on Shabbat (outside Israel), and there are hakafot, dancing, Chattan Torah, Breishit, etc.)

I am curious if those that followed the triennial cycle also had a "Simchat Torah" in the same fashion, i.e. - coinciding with a Yom Tov, and with hakafot, etc.? When would that have occurred? Was it on a fixed calendar date?

Comment: I think your title is quite unclear because the term "simchat torah" can have multiple connotations. Please clarify.

Comment: Yom tov no, but they almost certainly had a celebration of source. See Avraham Yaari's book (I can give you a page number in a few more hours when I get home)

Comment: Since the traditional triennial cycle always began a new book on one of the four New Years (see http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14508-triennial-cycle), there was an ambient celebration of sorts at the start of bereshit.

Comment: @Matt does that book provide evidence that a holiday centered around the completion of the Torah existed since the time that Jews were still using the triennial system?