# What is the last day to shake the lulav in Diaspora?

Tags: chutz-laaretz, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, shmini-atzeres

Do we shake the lulav on shemini atzeret or simhat torah for folks living in diaspora?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=268

Comment: Why do you think it would make a difference if someone was in the Diaspora or in Eretz Yisrael?

Comment: Shokhet, there are certain halachic differences between jewish practices inside and outside of Eretz Yisrael-a lot of them pertain to sukkot.

Answer (score 2):

We do not do so. You didn't ask why not, but, for anyone interested, there are [good and ample reasons](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10786).