# Should a Jew from outside Israel who is visiting Israel for Sukkot eat in the Sukkah on Shemini Atseret?

Tags: halacha, eretz-yisrael, chutz-laaretz, sukkah, shmini-atzeres

[Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shemini_Aseret#cite_ref-7) writes that

> Outside Israel, on the eighth day of Sukkot (first day of Shemini
>   Atseret), one should eat in the Sukkah without a Bracha of Leshev
>   BaSukkah.

The source for this is quoted as Rambam (Sukkah 6:13), Tur and S”A 668:1.

The question is what should someone who lives outside Israel  do on  Shemini Atseret if he is eating with a family who live in Israel and who therefore eat in the house.

Halachipedia says

> A Jew from outside Israel who is visiting Israel for Sukkot should not
>   eat in the Sukkah if it’s difficult to sit alone in the Sukkah.

and quotes Nitai Gavriel (Hilchot Arbah Minim Sh”t 8), Sh”t Minchat Yitzchak 9:54, Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Auerbach in Sh”t Minchat Shlomo 1:19, Rabbi Ovadyah Yosef in Chazon Ovadyah Sukkot(pg 480-1), Ot Hei LeOlam (vol 2 pg 87c; quoted by Sdei Chemed Sukkah 1) as sources.

Chazon Ovadyah Sukkot (pg 480-1) writes explicitly that if it’s not difficult to eat in the Sukkah such as one is staying by himself then he should sit in the Sukkah. However, Sh”t Minchat Shlomo 1:19 exempts such a person in all circumstances. So writes the Piskei Teshuvot 668:2 in name of Sh”t Minchat Yitzchak and Sh”t Minchat Shlomo.

What practical rulings have been heard on this subject?

Comment: You quote answers in your question already... Do you want a survey of what Yodeyan's LOR's have said? Of what use is that?

Comment: I do want a survey of Yodeyan's LOR's answers. I do not know to what extent people follow the answers given.

Comment: Note that even if you don't sit in the Sukkah on Shmini Atzeret in northern latitudes you may have to do so in Israel because the weather is comfortable. See answer 2 here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/46090/759.

Answer (score 2):

The Rabbi of my shul spoke about this question this year. He said that in Israel, a person from chutz la'aretz *should* sit in a sukkah lechatchila on Shmini Atzeret.

Comment: even when eating with the "locals"?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok It's hard to imagine a scenario where eating in a Sukkah with locals could be done in a lechatchilah manner.

Comment: @avrohom the rabbi related a personal story from when he was a bachur where he didn't realize that he was supposed to sit in a sukkah on Shmini Atzeret and made plans to eat out. His rebbe instructed him to cancel his plans in order to eat in a sukkah.

Comment: @DoubleAA find a sukkah with half the s'chach removed; the ben chu"l sits on the side under the s'chach, while the locals sit under the clear sky ...